# Why can't I use my methods within a method?

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, visual-studio, mobile-development

I am trying to make an iOS app to calculate quadratic equations. I am fairly new to all this UIKit stuff so after long days of trying to figure out how I could fix this, I still have no answer, hence why I am asking this question. I am trying to make a button display 2 different answers in 2 boxes, as you would, in a quadratic equation. I do not know what I may have done wrong and I don't know if it's something external to this code. Thanks in advance.

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace Quadeq
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public static void Calculatebutton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            static void idk(Answer1 hi, Textfield3 c, Textfield2 b, textfield1 a, bool pos)
            {
                string quad = Convert.ToString(quadform(a, b, c, true));
                hi.Text = quad;

            }
            static void idek(Answer2 heyy, Textfield3 c, Textfield2 b, textfield1 a, bool pos)
            {
                string quad = Convert.ToString(quadform(a, b, c, false));
                heyy.Text = quad;

            }
            idk();
            idek();
        }

        static void idk(Answer1 hi, Textfield3 c, Textfield2 b, textfield1 a, bool pos)
        {
            string quad = Convert.ToString(quadform(a, b, c, true));
            hi.Text = quad;
        }
        static void idek(Answer2 heyy, Textfield3 c, Textfield2 b, textfield1 a, bool pos)
        {
            string quad = Convert.ToString(quadform(a, b, c, false));
            heyy.Text = quad;
        }
        static int Textnumber1(UITextField t)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(t.Text);
            return num;
        }
        static double quadform(textfield1 a, Textfield2 b, Textfield3 c, bool pos)
        {
            int okay = Textnumber1(a);
            int owkie = Textnumber1(b);
            int yay = Textnumber1(c);

            var preRoot = owkie * owkie - 4 * okay * yay;
            if (preRoot < 0)
            {
                return double.NaN;
            }
            else
            {
                var sgn = pos ? 1.0 : -1.0;
                return (sgn * Math.Sqrt(preRoot) - owkie) / (2.0 * okay);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: This language is c#.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you aren't passing any arguments to the methods when calling them

```
idk();
idek();
```

Comment: yes, but im not sure what arguments I should pass because the text is inputted into the UITextfields.